# Simple circuits for send electrical shocks through a body

Tags: capacitor, analog, safety

The problem that I'm working on is a "reminder" type device that stimulates different areas of the body using electroshocks. Whilst the circuit is simple and doable with just a capacitor and a remote controlled switch I am at a loss when it comes to finding resources about the effects of electrical current when passing through the human body.

Most books I've read on analog circuits deal with bodies made up of a homgenous material that is either a conductor, an insulator, or a semiconductor clearly defined by a single value such as R,F,L... etc.

Is there a way to model a part of the human body as an electrical circuit to understand what type of capacitor to use in order not to cause harm and obtain the desired effect ? What is a good place to start in the study of such devices ?

Comment: Try the medical field - electroshock therapy etc

Comment: Why use a capacitor to shock somebody?  I'd use a large inductor with a current limiting resistor in series.  Put the dummy in parallel with the inductor, connect the power supply, disconnect and zap.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously this is a risky project since any design errors or circuit malfunctions could be fatal. It should not be attempted on a hobby basis. A professional design should be peer reviewed by experts in the field.

You will find hints about the amount of current that is considered non-lethal by studying the human models and the resulting design requirements for GFCI devices in the United States. There is also a substantial body of work in the related UL requirements.

Comment: Could you possibility provide some links ? I've found a lot of "requirements" when in comes to GFI/RCD but nothing related to a 'useable' model of the human body.

Comment: Also, as a rule of thumb, for safety, I am always using a 5v battery with a 1k R connected to it... which depending on the capacitor's maximum potential charge and my body could still be unsafe, but, in practice, I've electrocuted myself in these types of scenario quite often and usually I barely feel it, but, yes, it would be nice to have some theoretical reassurance rather than just making a "reasonable guess".